# How to get source code link for selection filter example

Tags: filter, selection

Below link not working?

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.SelectionFilter

Please help

Comment: Error 404 is clear, but here is not the place for that

Answer (score 0):

Some folders changed in this project, so it's not a good idea to keep this kind of link.
Hopefully you can still find this extension :
[Viewing.Extension.SelectionFilter](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/components/Viewer/Extensions/Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.SelectionFilter)